# SQL - Get databases which contain a specific record

Tags: mysql

So originally I have this as a test run.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_schema FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema LIKE '%or';
```

I have looked around and found queries to show all the databases that contain a specific table.

However is it possible to have a query to go a step further and do the following:

"Select all those databases that have a particular table in them and that, in that table, have a particular record in a particular column."?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want with a SQL statement.

But, you can use SQL to generate the statement that you want.  The basic statement is:

```
select "tablename"
from tablename
where columnname = value
limit 1
```

Note that value may need to have single quotes around it.  You can generate this with:

```
select concat('select "', c.table_name, '" ',
              'from ', c.schema_name, '.', c.table_name, ' ',
              'where ', c.column_name, ' = ', VALUE, ' '
              'limit 1'
             )
from information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = TABLENAME and c.column_name = COLUMN_NAME;
```

To put all the statements in one long SQL statement, use:

```
select group_concat(concat('select "', c.table_name, '" as table_name',
                           'from ', c.schema_name, '.', c.table_name, ' ',
                           'where ', c.column_name, ' = ', VALUE, ' '
                           'limit 1'
                          ) SEPARATOR ' union all '
                   )
from information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = TABLENAME and c.column_name = COLUMN_NAME;
```

I would then just copy the resulting SQL statement and run it.  If you like, you can add a `prepare` statement and run it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

as an example,
I have a table named T1 with columns (C1,C2), and I am searching for the value 'Needle'.

What this store procedure does is search through table names that starts with T and columns that starts with C, then loop through them and finds the value 'Needle'.  It then returns the table_Schema,table_name,column_name and how many times the value 'Needle' is found within that column_name,table_name,table_schema combination.

see this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a1a99/1/0)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findDatabase(IN in_value varchar(50))
BEGIN
  DECLARE bDone INT;
  DECLARE _TableSchema VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE _TableName VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE _ColumnName VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE "T%" AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE "C%"; 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tblResults;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblResults  (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    tableSchema varchar(50),
    tablename varchar(50),
    columnname varchar(50),
    timesFound int
  );

  OPEN curs;
  SET bDone = 0;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs INTO _TableSchema,_TableName,_ColumnName;
    SET @found = 0;
    SET @sql = CONCAT("SET @found = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ",_TableSchema,".",_TableName,
                      " WHERE ",_ColumnName,"='",in_value,"')");
    PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE statement;
    IF (@found > 0) THEN
       INSERT INTO tblResults(tableSchema,tableName,columnName,TimesFound) VALUES (_TableSchema,_TableName,_ColumnName,@found);
    END IF;
  UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

  CLOSE curs;
  SELECT DISTINCT TableSchema,TableName,ColumnName,TimesFound FROM tblResults;
  DROP TABLE tblResults;
END//
```